# how to achieve fragment blur effect from paint.net in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, paint.net

I used the fragment blur effect in paint.net on some text to achieve this really cool effect. I'm wanting to do the same thing in photoshop. Is this possible? if so, how?'

Here's what I was able to do in pain.net:
[image: fragment blur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy your text layer three times and put those copies under your original one. Change opacity of below layers and offset each of them `up`, `down` and `right` respectively until you get this effect.

Before making copies you can convert text layer to `smart object` so when you change it, all the copies get updated as well.